# Resolving breeze query/Q promise with $route resolve stops page

Tags: angularjs, breeze, q

I'm having problems executing a breeze query with angular resolve before the view is rendered. I'm trying to get some data from the server before the view is rendered with breeze. I'm using

```
$routeProvider.when('/countries', { templateUrl: 'App/partials/countries.html', controller: Ctrl, resolve: Ctrl.resolve }).
```

controller and service snippets:

```
function Ctrl($scope, Q, datacontext, countries) {

//...

}

function getCountries(forceRefresh) {

            var query = entityQuery.
                from("countries").
                orderBy("name");

            return manager.executeQuery(query).
            then(getSucceeded);

        }

        function getSucceeded(data) {
            return data.results;
        }
```

this makes my view never render:

```
Ctrl.resolve = {
    countries: function (datacontext) {
        return datacontext.getCountries();
    }
}
```

whereas if I create a timer that takes longer time, it works. I've tried wrapping it with $q but I can't seem to get it to work.

this will render the view because of the timeout:

```
Ctrl.resolve = {
    countries: function (datacontext) {
        return datacontext.getCountries();


    },
    delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        $timeout(delay.resolve, 6000);
        return delay.promise;
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me with this, it would be great. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there are limitations with Q promises or breeze in resolve.

Comment: angular promises are integrated with the digest cycle, while q has no idea about "the angular way". That might be the reason. It works with $timeout because it is integrated with / kicks off the digest cycle. Have you tried to set the timeout to 0?

Comment: It doesn't work until around 2000. I've been trying to make angular wait for q, but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 6):

I feel your pain. One of the mistakes in the $q/route resolve implementation is that the resolve does not honor the `Q.then` method. That violates the generally accepted practice of supporting interchangeable promise implementations (sigh).

But that's not the real problem. The real problem is that Angular doesn't know when your async method is resolved. You have to call `$rootScope.$apply` manually in both success and failure callbacks. Angular's $http and $q do this (or equivalent) for you. Getting it right yourself is a PITA.

As I said, we feel your pain. Very soon we will release a tiny Q plug-in that converts a Q promise to $q promise and should alleviate that pain. At least it does for me :-).

In a nutshell, find a place near where your app starts and extend Q something like this:

```
angular.module('app').factory('util', ['$q', '$rootScope', util]);

function util($q, $rootScope) {

   extendQ();

   ... other utilities here ...

   // Monkey patch to$q method into Q.js' promise prototype
   // ex usage: return manager.executeQuery(qry).to$q(succ, fail);
   function extendQ() {
       var promise = Q.defer().promise;
       var fn = Object.getPrototypeOf(promise);
       if (fn.to$q) return; // already extended
       fn.to$q = function (success, fail) {
           return to$q(this, success, fail);
       };
   }

   function to$q(qPromise, success, fail) {
       var d = $q.defer();
       qPromise
           .then(function (data) {
               if (data === undefined) {
                   logger.logError("Programming error: no data. " +
                   "Perhaps success callback didn't return a value or " +
                    "fail callback didn't re-throw error");
                   // If an error is caught and not re-thrown in an earlier promise chain
                   // you will arrive here with data === undefined. 
                   // Neglecting to re-throw is a common, accidental omission.
                   // To be safe, have every success callback return something
                   // and trap here if data is ever undefined
               }
               d.resolve(data);
               $rootScope.$apply();// see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/LQoBCQ-V_tM
           })
          .fail(function (error) {
              d.reject(error);
              $rootScope.$apply();// see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/LQoBCQ-V_tM
          });

       if (success || fail) {
           d.promise = d.promise.then(success, fail);
       }
       return d.promise;
   }
```

Now use it like this (based on your example):

```
function getCountries() {

    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("countries").orderBy("name");

    return manager.executeQuery(query).to$q(getSucceeded);

    function getSucceeded(data) { return data.results; }
}
```

### Addendum

I have been asked:

"*Why so complicated? Why don't you use `$q.when(qPromse)` to convert Q promise to $q promise?*"

I tried that ... and couldn't make it work. Specifically, I tried this:

```
function to$q(qPromise, success, fail) {
    var promise = $q.when(qPromise);
    if (success || fail) {
       promise = promise.then(success, fail);
    }
    return promise;
}
```

I believe there is something wrong with `$q.when`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I was playing with the $rootScope.$apply(), but I always tend to trigger the digest error so I think I need to read up on that.
Yes it would be great if they where interchangeable, $q respect q or breeze wit $q. 
I know this might not be a good PR thing to have on your page, but it would actually be great with a "known issues/limitations" kind of page for breeze/angular. Sometimes I feel like I spend quite some time trying to do "impossible" things.