# AngularJS dataservice using breezejs it not resolving the promise

Tags: angularjs, breeze, promise

I'm trying to setup a data service in my Angular application that is using breezeJS. After I resolve my promise I can't get the .then to file in my controller.  I am getting data back from my database via breeze in my data service.  I could just pass back the breeze promise but I want to be able to use $q.all to know when all my data has been found.

In my controller`

ProApp.controller('caseInfoController',
             function caseInfoController($scope, $log, $timeout, caseDataService)    {

```
    /***initialize data ***/
   // initializeApp();


    ATPinitializeApp();


    function ATPinitializeApp() {

        $scope.MyStateList=   caseDataService.getAllStates()
         .then(function assignStates(data) {
             $log.info("THIS THEN WILL NOT FIRE");               
         });

    }
```

`

The above then will not fire when the promise from the data service is fulfilled.

```
ProApp.factory('caseDataService', function ($log, $q)
{

breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);


var servicename = "http://localhost:60882/breeze/SPLBreeze";
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(servicename);

var caseDataService =
{
   getAllStates: getAllStates,

};

return caseDataService;

/*** implementation details ***/


function getAllStates()
{

  var myStatePromise = $q.defer();

  var query = breeze.EntityQuery
      .from("state");

  manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(function (data) {
        $timeout(function () { myStatePromise.resolve(data); }, 200);;
    });

  return myStatePromise.promise;
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm not 100% sure if I have the $q promises set up correctly.  Eventually I would like to use a $q.all to determine when an array of various promises have been resolved to so I can update a message to the user.   I've been reading that I need to use a timeout to get angular to realize that a change has happened in the next event loop.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is with your promises, but as per the angular/timeout thing: setting the timeout to 1ms should suffice. There's no need to set it to 200.

Comment: I think I can even leave it it off the default is 0 and optional.    $timeout(function(){stateListQ.resolve(); } );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're staring down the barrel of an Angular $q bug. You can read about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/LQoBCQ-V_tM) if you wish.

That won't help nearly as much as following the advice in [**my answer to this related StackOverflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724519/resolving-breeze-query-q-promise-with-route-resolve-stops-page/17733185#17733185) in which I show and describe an adapter to get from Q.js promise to a $q promise.

Comment: Thanks for the help !  I was thinking that I can just use Q.js instead of $q.  In my data service factory I just ended up defining a Q.js promise instead of an angular promise.   var myStatePromise = Q.defer();     I can't think of any downside since I already have to "apply" the changes.

Comment: ... if I don't want to manually resolve the Q promise I can just return the Q promise that Breeze is creating.   return manager.executeQuery(stateQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used breeze but I think your problem is that you are not returning anything on the success callback..

```
  /***initialize data ***/
    . . .
    function ATPinitializeApp() {

        $scope.MyStateList=   caseDataService.getAllStates()
         .then(function assignStates(data) {
             $log.info("THIS THEN WILL NOT FIRE");  
             return data; // If you don´t return anything nothing will be added to the scope.
         });

    }
```

Also the $timeout on the getAllStates function should not be necesary since angular resolves the promises asynchronously (it queues the resolution using $rootScope.$evalAsync)

```
function getAllStates()
{
. . .

  manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(function (data) {
       // I believe the $timeout that was in this function is not necessary
       myStatePromise.resolve(data);
    });

  return myStatePromis

e.promise;

}
```

Hope this could help you a little bit.

Regards,

Carles