# Attempting to use a mocked data store with breeze.js, custom JsonResultsAdapter, and mockJson AJAX adapter

Tags: ajax, breeze

I have been trying to figure out what is going wrong here for some time now. I have created a mockJson adapter to intercept Ajax requests. I basically just call the success method inside my adapter instead of making an Ajax call. As you can see I am using mockJson to spoof some JSON data.

```
ctor.prototype.ajax = function (config) {

    var jqConfig = {
        type: config.type, 
        url: config.url,
        data: config.params || config.data,
        dataType: config.dataType,
        contentType: config.contentType,
        crossDomain: config.crossDomain
    }

    if (!core.isEmpty(this.defaultSettings)) {
        var compositeConfig = core.extend({}, this.defaultSettings);
        jqConfig = core.extend(compositeConfig, jqConfig);
    }

    jqConfig.success = function (data, textStatus, XHR) {

        var httpResponse = {
            data: data.results,
            //status: XHR.status,
            //getHeaders: getHeadersFn(XHR),
            config: config
        };
        config.success(httpResponse);
        //XHR.onreadystatechange = null;
        //XHR.abort = null;
    };
    jqConfig.error = function (XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var httpResponse = {
            data: XHR.responseText,
            status: XHR.status,
            getHeaders: getHeadersFn(XHR),
            error: errorThrown,
            config: config
        };
        config.error(httpResponse);
        XHR.onreadystatechange = null;
        XHR.abort = null;
    };

    jqConfig.success($.mockJSON.generateFromTemplate({
        "results|1-1": [{
            "id|+1": 1,
            "$type": "Campaign",
            "name": "Campaign Name",
            "startDate": "2013-12-03T00:00:00.000",
            "budget|1-3000": 1
        }]
    }), null, null);

};
```

This returns a single result right now for simplicity. Next I have a custom JsonResultsAdapter as well. This is to basically map the $type property to the meta information required for entity translation:

```
      function configureBreezeManager() {

        var jsonResultsAdapter = new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({
            name: "mockJson",
            extractResults: function (json) {
                return json.results;
            },
            visitNode: function (node, mappingContext, nodeContext) {

                var entityType = node["$type"];

                return {
                    entityType: entityType
                };
            }
        });

        var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
            serviceName: config.remoteServiceName,
            jsonResultsAdapter: jsonResultsAdapter,
            hasServerMetadata: false // don't ask the server for metadata
        });

        var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: dataService });
        model.configureMetadataStore(mgr.metadataStore);

        //are we debugging? Lets use mockJson
        if (config.debugEnabled())
            breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("ajax", "mockJson", true);

        return mgr;
    }
```

Lastly, I have my metadata model object being created and called before my query :

```
    function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {

        addLookupTypes(metadataStore);
        addCampaignType(metadataStore);
        addMessageType(metadataStore);

        metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Campaigns', 'Campaign');
        metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Messages', 'Message');
        metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Demos', 'Demo');

        referenceCheckValidator = createReferenceCheckValidator();
        Validator.register(referenceCheckValidator);

        log('Validators registered');
    }

        function addCampaignType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "Campaign",
            namespace: "My.Models",
            dataProperties: {
                id: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
                name: { dataType: DataType.String, maxLength: 30, isNullable: false }
            }
        });

        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Campaign", null, campaignInitializer);
    }

    function campaignInitializer(campaign) {
        campaign.errorMessage = ko.observable();

        campaign.startDateFormatted = ko.computed(function () {
            return moment(campaign.startDate()).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
        });
    }
```

My query :

```
         var query = EntityQuery.from('Campaigns').
            select('id, name, startDate, budget')
            .orderBy(orderBy.campaign);
```

First off, I didn't think I would need a custom JsonResultsAdapter if I am basically spoofing data in the form of a normal WebApi response, but alas I set it up based on some StackOverflow posts. The problem I am having are the Entities being returned are not having the properties wrapped as knockout observables. Later code is failing because of this and I will not be able to utilize all the aspects of breeze without this happening. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response Ward. I simplified everything and actually tested with a real server response as you suggested. When I did this, it was still broken. I then tried to compare the differences between my application and another one I did that works for me. The issue was inside my app when loading knockout, it was being loaded differently with require.js than Breeze expected.

This article captures what was happening : [BreezeJS integration with DurandalJS issues related to how KnockoutJS is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006421/breezejs-integration-with-durandaljs-issues-related-to-how-knockoutjs-is-loaded)

So I realized knockout wasn't being found and added the following code to my main.js file of durandal to map knockout differently so it can be found :

```
map: {
    '*': { 'knockout': 'ko' }
}
```

Thanks again for responding. Is there a way Breeze can alert you that it can't instantiate knockout?

I see this in code : ko = core.requireLib("ko", "The Knockout library");

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of moving parts here. I'd be more inclined to take a simpler path.

As I read you, you're trying to create some mock data during development, not testing (if you were testing I'd be talking about sinon.js).

I wouldn't mess with the jsonResultsAdapter unless you're simulating a conversation with a data source we don't support out of the box. You didn't say. Let's suppose that you're trying to emulate the JSON.NET result returned by an ASP.NET Web API (you can correct me if I've guessed wrong).

I noticed that your mock JSON result has camelCase properties. That's not what I'd expect from a server-side business model written in a statically typed language where the convention is PascalCase. Here, for example, is a snippet from the response for "Rooms":

```
{
    $id: "2",
    $type: "CC.Model.Room, CC.Model",
    Id: 1,
    Name: "Surf A"
},
{
    $id: "3",
    $type: "CC.Model.Room, CC.Model",
    Id: 2,
    Name: "Surf B"
},
```

I noticed that your model class has a namespace, "My.Models", so I would expect you to generate $type like "My.Models.Campaign, My.Models".

Those are just a couple of possible disconnects.

It might be faster to create a throw-away database, populate it with a few pieces of data, and hit with a breeze client to see what it is you should be matching with your mocks vis-a-vis the metadata and JSON responses.

HTH