# How to extend breeze to be interoperable with standard CommonJS promises spec

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I have monkey patched the breeze EntityManager.prototype so that it returns angular $q promises whilst also calling $rootScope.$apply (using code similar to [Ward Bell's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724519/resolving-breeze-query-q-promise-with-route-resolve-stops-page/17733185#answer-17733185)).

However, this falls down in one important respect: **code internal to breeze registers errorCallbacks using the `fail` method on the promise object** (eg promise.then(callback).fail(errCallback)

The `fail` method is not part of the CommonJS promise/A+ specification, and as such is not included in the angularjs promise api. The consequence is that the angularjs promise that the EntityManager.prototype is now returning does not have the fail method and so an exception is thrown.

**QUESTION**: is there a way of customizing breezejs so as to support only the promise api included in the CommonJS/A+ spec without me having to directly modifying the breezejs library itself? As suspect not, so I have also raise a [breeze change request](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4324769-better-integration-with-angularjs).

Thanks
Christian Crowhurst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please do not monkey patch the breeze `EntityManager` prototype with $q**. You are breaking the warranty when you do that. Just don't.

Breeze uses [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) for promises and Q is CommonJS compliant.  Q is a rock-solid promise implementation; $q ... not so much.

If anything you should be complaining that $q is out of compliance with the spec precisely because it calls `$apply` which is a side effect that is often unwanted especially in testing. Don't get me started.

The `fail` method is just Q sugar, an extension of `then`. We like its readability and we use it.

> You could add a `fail` method to the $q promise promise if you liked. Pretty simple. Something along the lines of an alias for `then(function(data){return data;}, failHandler)`

You could make the case that we should not use the Q `fail` method internally and instead limit our use of promises inside our Breeze components to just those members identified in the CommonJS spec. I'll forward that thought internally. It would certainly facilitate the possibility of alternatives to Q. I personally dislike that Breeze has any dependencies on 3rd party libraries, even a library as stellar as Q.

Trust me, we considered this. There is one hurdle we cannot clear: **most promise implementations are crap**.

Breeze depends upon a promise library that behaves properly under all conditions and especially in its handling of exceptions. If we opened this door, people would start plugging in any promise library they wanted ... anything with a "then" method. Their Breeze apps would start to break in mysterious and untimely ways. We'd get calls telling us that Breeze is crap.

Case in point: jQuery. The jQuery deferred is a broken implementation. If someone used that in place of Q, Breeze apps would break. Not all of the time ... which is worse than breaking all the time.

I will not say `$q` is crap. I will say that it is unsound ... and not just because it always calls (or does the equivalent of calling) $apply.

Let me say again what I said at the top: please do not monkey patch the breeze `EntityManager` prototype with $q.

I can imagine *why* you want to do that. You want the promise returned from an `EntityManager` method to be a $q promise. Sorry. Bad idea.

Please follow my recommendation instead. [Use our `to$q` extension to Q.js](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/toqjs) (documentation forthcoming). It's easy to "install" after which, instead of this:

```
var QPromise1 = someQuery.using(manager).execute();
var QPromise2 = anotherQuery.using(manager).execute().then(success, fail);
```

you write this:

```
var $qPromise1 = someQuery.using(manager).execute().to$q();
var $qPromise2 = anotherQuery.using(manager).execute().to$q(success, fail);
```

How hard is that?

Comment: Hey Ward, thanks for your detailed comment. Totally understand where you're coming from here. I was torn between doing as you mention and going with the monkey patch that I ended up doing. My plan was to go with the monkey patch, monitor for any breeze side effects. If there weren't any then stick with the monkey patch, if there are fallback to having devs remember to call to$q. Thanks Ward mate.

Comment: Yes ... I think it best to stick with to$q even if it is another thing to remember. Obviously you could add a `fail` method to $q and monkey patch the EntityManager. But I don't like that. $q is to fragile. It wrecks your async tests. And it always calls the equivalent of $apply which means you could incur unwanted digest cycles. The good thing about to$q is that, if something goes wrong, it goes wrong in your code, outside of Breeze, where it is much easier to understand, debug, and fix.

Comment: I had a go at monkey patching $q with a fail method. It's not really doable as the $q promises do not assign a prototype which can be extended. I tried extending the promise instance returned by $q.defer(), but then any subsequent promises created by chaining a call to "then" to this promise will not have the fail method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Breeze response (using a [Breeze Labs](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/what-are-breeze-labs) disclaimer) is:

[to$q - a bridge to Angular promises](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/toqjs)

"A BreezeJS asynchronous method returns a promise, typically a promise to deliver some data from a remote service (or an error if the service request fails).

Breeze methods return Q.js promises not AngularJS $q promises. The to$q plugin makes it easy to transition from a Breeze Q promise to an Angular $q promise."